# jQuery CSS selector not working, what's wrong?

Tags: css, jquery-selectors

I am trying to identify and select elements based on their hierarchical css selectors.

Let's take as an example the Reddit logo at www.reddit.com.

A script gives me

```
"html>body>div:eq(0)>div:eq(1)>a"
```

is this a valid selector?

both

```
alert($('html>body>div:eq(0)>div:eq(1)>a').html());
```

and

```
alert($('div:eq(0) > div:eq(1) > a').html());
```

return 'undefined' instead of 'reddit.com'.

Comment: Going to reddit and typing `window.jQuery('html>body>div:eq(0)>div:eq(1)>a').html()` in my debug window works fine for me. Maybe they have jQuery running under `$.noConflict` (making `$` unavailable)?

Comment: Probably you have some addons installed that change the structure of the DOM, did you look at the actual elements tree or at the source code?

Comment: If @BradChristie had his method work then you might have a conflict issue with the `$` sign. Reddit uses many scripts and might be using `$` for something else. Try using `jQuery` instead.

Comment: @harryg it also works with `$`  (Chrome 27.0)

Comment: I am an idiot: the script is outside an iframe in which I loaded a copy of reddit.com, hence the path I receive is wrong. 

`alert($('#iframe').contents().find('div:eq(0) > div:eq(1) > a').html());`

works like a charm. Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script that gives me the path is outside an iframe in which I loaded a copy of reddit.com, hence the path I receive is wrong.

```
alert($('#iframe').contents().find('div:eq(0) > div:eq(1) > a').html());
```

works perfectly.